# Is there any reason to refactor declaration functions into an expression function?

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

I have these 3 functions, they are different but all of them happen in the same context, they are related, so they have some components in commons (ex: class names).

```
function btnSubmitLoading($btn, cleanError, classToRemove) {
    // 5-10 lines of code
}

function btnSubmitComplete($btn, classToAdd) {
    // other 5-10 lines of code
}

function btnFeedback($btn, $msg, classToAdd) {
    // more 5-10 lines of code
}
```

They are declared before $(document).ready(), so they are global and called in different pages. When I need one of them:

```
btnFeedback($('button'), 'success', 'fa-check');
```

My question here is if there is any reason to transform these functions into an expression function, resulting in something like this:

```
var ButtonSubmit = function() {

    this.btnSubmitLoading = function($btn, cleanError, classToRemove) {
        // 5-10 lines of code
    }

    this.btnSubmitComplete = function($btn, classToAdd) {
         // other 5-10 lines of code
    }

    this.btnFeedback = function($btn, $msg) {
        // more 5-10 lines of code
    }
}
```

Call it:

```
btnFancy = new ButtonSubmit();
```

And when I need it:

```
btnFancy.btnFeedback($('button'), 'success', 'fa-check');
```

I've been learning about expression / declaration functions and closure / prototype, but I still don't understand where should I apply each of them.

Thanks.

Comment: If anything it appears you should refactor that into a proper constructor function accepting something like `new ButtonSubmit($('button'))`, and those methods should be on the `prototype`, and omit their first `$btn` parameter. Otherwise this is pretty pointless.

Comment: hmm... could you show me an example to better understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `ButtonSubmit` class/constructor function doesn't really do anything, that's pretty pointless. At the very least you'd want to use it to simplify your use of the object to this:

```
let btnFancy = new ButtonSubmit($('button'));
btnFancy.feedback('success', 'fa-check');
```

(I don't know if that makes any sense for your use case or not.)

You'd implement that like this:

```
function ButtonSubmit(button) {
    this.button = button;
}

ButtonSubmit.prototype.submitLoading = function (cleanError, classToRemove) {
    this.button....
    // 5-10 lines of code
}

ButtonSubmit.prototype.submitComplete = function (classToAdd) {
    this.button....
    // 5-10 lines of code
}

ButtonSubmit.prototype.feedback = function ($msg) {
    this.button....
    // 5-10 lines of code
}
```

If that doesn't make a lot of sense to you and you just want to namespace your functions, you don't need a function or `new`:

```
let btn = {
    submitLoading: function ($btn, cleanError, classToRemove) {
        // 5-10 lines of code
    }
    submitComplete: function ($btn, classToAdd) {
        // other 5-10 lines of code
    },
    feedback: function ($btn, $msg, classToAdd) {
        // more 5-10 lines of code
    }
}

btn.feedback($('button'), ...);
```

Comment: Okay, I think the second examples `let btn = { ....` is the best option because there are a lot of buttons, so create a new ButtonSubmit() for each button is awful, right?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Will you apply multiple operations to the same button? Then `new ButtonSubmit($('button'))` makes sense. If it's just a one-off for many many buttons OTOH, one-off functions will do.

Comment: by "multiple operations" do you mean besides  "let btn = {...}" ?. If so, nop. Almost all the buttons have only these 3 functions. Well, thanks for the help!